# How are the kids who walk with players into a football match selected?

Tags: football

This question has been on my mind for quite some time. Before a football match starts, be it the Premier League or international, the players of either teams walk in usually with a kid dressed in opposing teams colors.

My question is how are these children nominated? Is there a selection process which they need to go through?

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, but it is mostly covered by [this answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/664/12).

Comment: In this case an in the other question, there is one big error, and that is that the process is totally localized to a country. For example in Argentina first the children where the players kids and friends, but now is totally forbiden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *mascots* who walk out with the football players are usually from local schools or football teams, selected from letters written in by themselves, winners of competitions run by the club or children with disabilities. Also when youth leagues become "partners" of the team by buying a team package etc., one of the perks is to have some of your players as an escort for a match, as well as serve as ball kids.