# In the Cricket and Soccer/Non-American Football World Cup, why do the players lead children during the beginning?

Tags: cricket, football, world-cup, cricket-world-cup

The title says it all, really. In the world cups for different sports, the player lead children on the field. Why?

Comment: Welcome. Is there anything you are looking for that may not be covered by the following two questions? http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/accompanying-children-for-national-anthem and http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/663/why-do-players-enter-with-children-on-the-ground